# Problems with encoding Website in Python. Getting 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x9f' in position

Tags: python, encoding, rss, codec, rss-reader

I want to build an RSS Feed Reader by myself. So I started up.

My Test Page, from where I get my feed is 'http://heise.de.feedsportal.com/c/35207/f/653902/index.rss'.

It is a German page , because of that I choose as decoding "iso-8859-1". So here is the code.

```
def main():
counter = 0
try:
    page = 'http://heise.de.feedsportal.com/c/35207/f/653902/index.rss'
    sourceCode = opener.open(page).read().decode('iso-8859-1')
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    #print sourceCode
try:
    titles = re.findall(r'<title>(.*?)</title>',sourceCode)
    links = re.findall(r'<link>(.*?)</link>',sourceCode)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))     
rssFeeds = []
for link in links:
    if "rss." in link:
        rssFeeds.append(link)
for feed in rssFeeds:
    if ('html' in feed) or ('htm' in feed):
        try:
            print("Besuche " + feed+ ":")
            feedSource = opener.open(feed).read().decode("iso-8859-1","replace")
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))   
        content = re.findall(r'<p>(.*?)</p>', feedSource)
        try:
            tempTxt = open("feed" + str(counter)+".txt", "w")
            for line in content:
                tempTxt.write(tagFilter(line))
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
        finally:
            tempTxt.close()
            counter += 1
            time.sleep(10)
```

1. First of all I start by opening the website I mentioned before. And so far there seems not to be any problem with opening it.
2. After decoding the website I search in it for all expression which are inside a Link Tags.
3. Now I select those links which have "rss" in them. Which get stored in a new list.
4. With the new list, I start opening the links and search there fore there content.

And now start the problems. I decode those sides, still german sides, and I get errors like:

- 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x9f' in position 339: character maps to
- 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x9c' in position 43: character maps to
- 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x80' in position 131: character maps to

And I really have no Idea why it won't work.
The data which is collected before the error appears gets written into an textfile.

Example for collected data:

Einloggen auf heise onlineTopthemen:Nachdem Google Anfang des Monats eine 64-Bit-Beta seines hauseigenen Browsers Chrome für Windows 7 und Windows 8 vorgestellt hatte, kümmert sich der Internetriese nun auch um OS X. Wie Tester melden, verbreitet Google über seine Canary-/Dev-Kanäle für Entwickler und Early Adopter nun automatisch 64-Bit-Builds, wenn der User über einen kompatiblen Rechner verfügt.

I hope someone can help me. Also other clues or information which will help me build my own rss feed reader are welcome.

Greetings Templum

Comment: Try UTF-8 instead of iso-8859-1.

Comment: You can't just make up an encoding. That page is encoded in utf-8, and the XML starts with a declaration that says just that.

Comment: And please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags before you even think of parsing XML with regular expressions.

Comment: @Wooble and also miko this for mentioning the UTF-8 thing. But I thought as it is an german side and they using special chars like ü and ä. It was just a mistake.....

Comment: What do you mean "except for the German parts"? UTF-8 can encode all of the unicode codepoints. I suggest you read http://bit.ly/unipain

Comment: @Wooble nevermind i mean there come a new error up character '\u0308' in position 139: character maps to <undefined>. But its mainly because it parses far more than the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per miko and Wooble's comment:

`iso-8859-1` should be `utf-8` since the XML returned says
the encoding is `utf-8`:

```
In [71]: sourceCode = opener.open(page).read()

In [72]: sourceCode[:100]
Out[72]: "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='http://heise.de.feedspo"
```

and you really ought to be using an XML parser like [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse XML. It's more error prone to be using only the `re` module.

---

`feedSource` is a `unicode` since it is the result of a decoding:

```
        feedSource = opener.open(feed).read().decode("utf-8","replace")
```

Therefore, `line` is also `unicode`:

```
    content = re.findall(r'<p>(.*?)</p>', feedSource)
    for line in content:
        ...
```

`tempTxt` is a plain file handle (as opposed to one opened with `io.open`, which takes an encoding parameter). So `tempTxt` expects bytes (e.g. a `str`), not `unicode`.

So encode the `line` before writing to the file:

```
        for line in content:
            tempTxt.write(line.encode('utf-8'))
```

or define `tempTxt` using `io.open` and specify an encoding:

```
import io
with io.open(filename, "w", encoding='utf-8') as tempTxt:
    for line in content:
        tempTxt.write(line)
```

---

By the way, it's not good to catch all Exceptions unless you are ready to handle all Exceptions:

```
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

and furthermore, if you only print the error message, then Python may execute subsequent code even though variables defined in the `try` section are undefined. For example,

```
    try:
        print("Besuche " + feed+ ":")
        feedSource = opener.open(feed).read().decode("iso-8859-1","replace")
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))   
    content = re.findall(r'<p>(.*?)</p>', feedSource)
```

using `feedSource` in the call to `re.findall` may raise a NameError if an exception was raised before `feedSource` was defined.

You might want to add a `continue` statement in the `except-suite` if you want Python to pass over this `feed` and move on to the next:

```
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))   
        continue
```

Comment: Thx for your clue with the continue didn't know it before. And also thanks so much for your effort